# Provide an empty argument to slurm job dependency options

Tags: slurm

How can I provide an empty argument to slurm's job dependency option, for example in:
sbatch --dependency=afterok:$job1_id job2.slurm

can I have $job1_id as a NULL or NIL or -1 or such. I am working with slurm version 22.05.2.

This is for scripting situations where $job1_id may exist or not.

Trying -1 (that worked with an earlier slurm version) now gives:

> sbatch --dependency=afterok:-1 job2.slurm
> sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Job dependency problem

Comment: Just remove the parameter.

Comment: Thanks Poshi. I want to include the parameter for situations where the job1_id may or may not exist - without having to workaround with an if statement.

Comment: In the case where the jobid does not exist, you will still need some kind of conditional to set the value you are asking for, right? Use that conditional to get rid of the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able or willing to change the script logic to avoid the argument all together, you can resort to replacing `-1` with the job ID of a previous job that completed properly.

If you are using the same script on multiple clusters, you can try `1` hoping it corresponds to a completed job on each of those clusters.